# How to bind method to an elements click in v-for cycle?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Iv got a v-for, and i need every element in this cycle to react on mouseclick. When i bind a method like i usually do, nothing happens. But outside the v-for this method i use seems to be working as expected.
What do i do wrong?

Here is the html code

```
<div v-for="day of days" v-on:click="dayClick(day.id)">
{{ day.day }}
</div>
```

This is vue app code

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
       days: [],
          },
     methods: {
        dayClick: function (dayId) {
            console.log(dayId);
         }
      }
})
```

When i bind this method to any other element outside the v-for, it works fine

Im getting days[] in mounted like this

````
axios({
   method: 'get',
   url: '{{URL::to('api/calendar/days')}}?token=' + this.user.token + '&userId=' + this.user.id
}).then((response) => {
   this.days = response.data.days;
   this.daysOfWeek = response.data.daysOfWeek;
  })```
````

Comment: Your `days` array is empty? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7w2oqdz/)

Comment: no, v-for generates elements, i would not be able to click them and check if it was empty. It now has hardcoded data for dev

Comment: ! moment came to my mind - days array is being filled with values in mounted. Can this be a reason? Is html being generatied before mounted run?

Comment: The code you have provided is bug-free, the bug is elsewhere. Can you provide more code, or even a fiddle? Can you show us how you are populating the days?

Comment: In jsfiddle my example works( IDK what the hell is it, Im getting days[] by axios async request in mounted section. Can it be a reason? https://jsfiddle.net/Ltgp97vy/  .

Comment: Are you sure the `dayClick` function isn't being called, or maybe `dayId` is undefined and it's logging nothing?

Comment: i even used aler to see if it is called....

Comment: When i copy my code to jsfiddle, it works perfectly. Its some kind of laravel blade shit i guess, or i surrender

Answer (score 0):

And if you do something like this?

```
<template v-for="(day) in days">
    <div v-on:click="dayClick(day.id)">
       {{ day.day }}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: i dont have a component in my app. its a single page stuff

Answer (score -1):

As it always appears - im my own worst enemy. I had `pointer-events: none;` for element i was trying to look at. Sry guys, and thank you for help. Im much more stupid than all of you